# matches(not(isDisplayed())) fails with NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-espresso-recorder

I am trying to test the absence of the UI view. The view selector is as follows:

```
public static ViewInteraction onMyTestUi() {
    return onView(withId(R.id.myTestId));
}
```

The selector works fine to check if the view is displayed, but gives error on checking if the view not displayed. I am using this as follows:

```
 onMyTestUi().check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

But I get the following error:

> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:
> No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: is   If
> the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use
> Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following
> AdapterViews:android.widget.ListView{...}

This is strange. I am checking the absence of the UI and its expected that this view won't be found. Then why Espresso is throwing error?
Please suggest what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Need to use `doesNotExist()` instead.
Found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes#asserting-view-not-present).

If the view is there in the view hierarchy but in an invisible state (visibility is set to 'INVISIBLE'), use `not(isDisplayed)`. However, if the view is not there at all in the view hierarchy (e.g. visibility set to 'GONE'), `doesNotExist()` is used.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but `onView(withId(R.id.myTestId)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));` did work.

Comment: @Sithu -It depends on the app. 
If the view you’re looking for is there in the view hierarchy but invisible, then you need to use not(isDisplayed). However, if the view is not there in the view hierarchy, you need to use doesNotExist().

Comment: I have the button in layout, but set visibility `View.GONE` in `onCreate` upon user role. So, does it mean that it is in the view hierarchy and invisible?

Comment: Yeah!  Thanks for this, super solved my problem, and makes my morning much better (went to bed with this issue).

Comment: If the view is gone from the view hierarchy—which can happen when an action caused a transition to another activity—you should use ViewAssertions.doesNotExist(): View.GONE example in your example is wrong and misleading. Please edit your answer

Comment: @metis and then how does the answer above makes it misleading? View.GONE is one of the examples when doesNotExist() can be used. Please try again. Thanks.

Comment: View.GONE works with not(isDisplayed() but does not work with doesNotExist().  doesNotExist returns true if visibility is GONE. I tried with example. In the link you gave there is nothing said related to View.GONE.

Comment: Pabel's answer works for me but this answer does not.  Mabye I'm doing something wrong and an actual example of the code would help

Answer (score 21):

Also work with yours method, but something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.next)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

Answer (score 20):

```
onView(withText("")).check(doesNotExist());
```

Comment: This is a partially correct answer. This will only work if targedet view does not exist in the layout (view hierarchy does not contain this view.) However, this assertion will fail if targeted view actually exists in the layout view hierarchy, but it's visibility state is GONE or INVISIBLE. Assertion failure message in that case will state: `android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: View is present in the hierarchy...`

Comment: Correct, so I think you could check the error message with the detailed view hierarchy.

Answer (score 14):

You can try this option if you check the view visibility "withEffectiveVisibility"

```
    onView(withId(R.id.YOURVIEW)).check(matches(ViewMatchers.withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.GONE)))
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check if `View` is either *not visible* or *does not exist*.

```
public static ViewAssertion isNotDisplayed() {
    return new ViewAssertion() {
        @Override
        public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noView) {
            if (view != null && isDisplayed().matches(view)) {
                throw new AssertionError("View is present in the hierarchy and Displayed: "
                        + HumanReadables.describe(view));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.someView)).check(isNotDisplayed());
```

Comment: Thanks for this - IMHO this is the best solution for a generalized "check if the view is gone from the screen". One correction, though: IME, the usage is `onView(withId(R.id.someView)).check(isNotDisplayed());`