# Espresso not throwing NoMatchingViewException when the visibility of the view is gone

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have an `Activity` which has two `Views` - which are shown depending on the network condition.

```
  LinearLayout recyclerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
  LinearLayout errorParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.error_parent);

  if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable()){
      recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      errorParent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }else{
      recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      errorParent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I have written an Espresso test for testing Network conditions. Before running the test, I manually switch off the Internet.

```
ViewInteraction viewInteraction = onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view));
viewInteraction.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Since there is no Internet, the `recycler_view` is `GONE`, and thus it is  not  present in the view hierarchy. But when running the code I am not getting `NoMatchingViewException`. Ideally when the view is not present in the hierarchy, I should get the above exception. Instead I am getting `AssertionFailedError`.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution here is to look into source code of `Espresso`. Let's trace down, what is happening.

When calling [`check(final ViewAssertion viewAssert)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/ViewInteraction.java#156) in this [line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/ViewInteraction.java#166), the view is checked whether it is in the hierarchy. The exception `NoMatchingViewException` is not caught, because `viewFinder` finds the view in the hierarchy. Then the code goes to [assertion](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/ViewInteraction.java#170). So the code goes funther to `ViewAssertion`'s function: [`matches(final Matcher<? super View> viewMatcher)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/ViewAssertions.java#73) with `missingViewException` being null.
In this [line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/ViewAssertions.java#81) `noViewException` is null, therefore code goes to [`assertThat`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/ViewAssertions.java#89). The assertion is [`isDisplayed()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java#110), which measures [global effective visibility of the view](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java#119). This is where `AssertionFailedError` is thrown.

For asserting wherther the view is not in visible in the current layout another construction should be used:

```
onView({Matcher<View>}).check(doesNotExist());
```

or

```
onView({Matcher<View>}).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

More explanation about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431647/matchesnotisdisplayed-fails-with-nomatchingviewexception)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I debugged by going through the steps which you mentioned and clearly Espresso is able to find the view in the hierarchy in this line  targetView = viewFinder.getView(), which returns targetView as non null. But if I go through UIAutomator, it does not show recycler_view in the hierarchy. So ideally it should not get the view here as well.

Comment: So I will assume that if the view was present in the hierarchy, and afterwards the visibility of the view has been set to GONE, then Espresso won't throw NoMatchingViewException.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is this is appropriate behavior. Your view is existing in your view hierarchy, is just not visible. You should get:

```
AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
```

Comment: But when we set the visibility of a view to GONE, doesn't android remove the view from the hierarchy. Even in the UIAutomator, I am not able to find the view.